# Curvature created by an object near Earth via energy-stress tensor

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, curvature, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

From Misner... who uses the convention of (-, +, +, +) for the metric $g^{\mu\nu}$,

with the electromagnetic stress energy tensor being(pg.141):

$$T^{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{\mu_0}(F^{\mu \alpha}F^{\nu}{}_{\alpha} - \frac{1}{4}g^{\mu\nu}F_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha \beta})$$

and then a positive sign for the stress energy tensor:

$$G_{\mu\nu} = 8\pi GT_{\mu\nu}$$

Imagine a scenario of a charged object near Earth or at Earth's surface. Its mass is negligible but its E and B fields are not negligible. Therefore, to find the electromagnetic stress energy tensor of this object near the curvature of Earth, I would use the Schwarzschild metric in the weak field approximation, with M being the mass of Earth, as the metric (after finding the inverse of course) in the formula, $g^{\mu\nu}$, for the electromagnetic stress energy tensor, correct?

Comment: No. The Schwarzschild metric doesn’t know about the charged object. Its Einstein tensor vanishes. In any case, the effect of the Earth on the electromagnetic field of the charged object is negligible. It is only important near the horizon of a black hole. By the way, there is an exact solution for the electrostatic field of a point charge at rest in a Schwarzschild metric!

Comment: If you were interested in the Earth’s tiny effect on the charged object’s stress energy tensor, I think you could use the formula for the stress tensor in terms of the flat-space fields and then do a perturbative calculation using the weak field limit of the metric.

Comment: The exact solution that I mentioned does not take the curvature due to the point charge into account. It only includes the curvature due to the black hole. But this is an excellent approximation, and you could compute the stress energy from the exact solution.

Comment: Exact solution is here: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/9/7/010/meta

Comment: So if I wanted to do a perturbation approach, I would find the flat spacetime solution then how would I use the weak field limit metric?

Comment: Is the flat space-time electromagnetic stress energy tensor enough of an approximation for a near Earth charged object?

Comment: Yes, it is an extremely good approximation. Physicists never take gravity into account when dealing with electromagnetism on Earth, except, perhaps when dealing with the tiny redshift/blueshift of light. For example, gravity’s effect on the energy levels of atoms, or on scattering experiments at the LHC, or on how an electric motor operates are not even measurable.